# map a @OneToMany relationship using a string column as a key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Good Morning!

I would like to know if there is a way to map a `@OneToMany` relationship using a string column as a key. The database in SQL Server already has all the tables, but their relationship was not made by the id, but by values ​​of type string. Can anyone help me?
Example:

`student table` with the fields `name, phone, email`the key of this table is the column "name"

`class table`with the fields `name, date, discipline` the key of this table is the column "name" that refers to "student name".

as I tried to do:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
  ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
  private List<Class> class = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Class{
  ...

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
  private Student student;
}
```

When I run it through H2, it creates a column with the students' id, but I would like it to map the data that is already in the database, because I can't change the data structure. Can someone help me?

Comment: did you try with something like this: `@JoinColumn(name = "student_your_desired_column_name")
private Student student;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is a valid type for an identifier. If you don't want an additional id column, you can map name as an identifier:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
  
  @Id
  @Column(name = "`name`")
  String name;
  
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
  private List<Class> class = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}
```

For some databases `name` is a special keyword, if you use `` @Column(name = "`name`") ``, Hibernate will handle it correctly.

Comment: No problem. By the way, `date`  seems the kind of name that can cause issues on a db. I don't know which db you are using, but it might be a good idea to also annotate that attribute with ```@Column(name=`date`)```

Comment: Sorry, you said in the question that you are using Sql Server. The list of reserved keywords is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16